# Flipped Normals cause Fluid to spill

Tags: normals, fluid-simulation, shadows

I tried to make an animation with fluids for the first time, and I modeled the jug without tutorial after one I have myself.
I used a cylinder as the geometry for the fluid, but the moment I started the simulation it started spilling out around the horizontal ring of faces at the bottom of the handle.
[image: Liquid spilling out at bottom of the handle]

When I checked the normals I noticed that they weren't pointing outside. The walls of the jug have thickness, and the normals on the inside all point correctly. To make sure, I flipped the normals of these faces, and the liquid actually stayed inside, however, now the shading for that area is messed up.

[image]

Does anyone have a tip how to fix this?

Edit: I managed to get all the normals flipped correctly, with it still looking correct, however, the fluid still spills at the same location.

Comment: search here for fluid problem -> there were dozens of questions like this

Comment: I did, all I could find was that I should check if the normals were flipped, which I did.

Comment: Did you raise resolution?

Comment: I had it at 128, which is about as much as my system can handle, but even at a small test at 256 it spills.

Answer (score 0):

I have now increased the minimum and maximum timestep of the simulation to 4 and 8, and it seems to have done the trick. Still not sure what was going on with the normals, but it looks okay for now.